# Error on uploading an image

Tags: php, image, fuelphp

I am using Fuel PHP framework and QQFileUpload to upload files.
When I am uploading images, the file gets uploaded but I get an error. The images won`t show up on the website. Any ideas?

Here is the error message I am getting:

> ErrorException [ Compile Error ]:
>   Access level to SmartImage\SmartImage_Gd::create_transparent_image() must be protected (as in class Fuel\Core\Image_Gd) or weaker

Comment: What is the platform of the server? I mean the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

This error suggests you have extended the `Image_Gd` class. In that class, the `create_transparent_image()` method is defined as protected. If you overload it, you must also define it as `protected`, or define it as `public` (which is weaker). This error suggests it is defined as `private`?

Answer (score -1):

mybe you need good img to upload it , try using photoshop and make any img if upload done then you have bad img format

Comment: It has nothing to do with this. I tried to upload a bunch set of images. None of them works.